# Jquery, Selector syntaxt help, get all text fileds

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a selector that works like this:

```
$('#container textarea, #container :text');
```

However this does not work.

```
$('#container').filter('textarea, :text');
```

Though, I have read that the filter command is the same as:

```
var context = $('#container');
$('textarea, :text', context);
```

Which does work

How can i get the the selector to work in the second expression?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want the second expression anyway? It *would* be less performant than the first.

Comment: Regardless of if the second expression *were* valid, given the option of directly selecting (i.e. `$()`) versus selecting then filtering (i.e. `$().filter()`), straight selection offers better performance. The former analyzes the DOM testing against your selector. The latter does the same, then does it again for the matching set. Extra step = extra cost. Admittedly this may be negligible. I'd like to see some benchmarks out there. Either way, the former expression reads better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you read this, it is wrong.

```
var context = $('#container');
$('textarea, :text', context);
```

is equivalent to using [**`.find()`**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('#container').find('textarea, :text');
```

`filter` filters the current selected elements, it does not search its descendants. So your second expression would return the element selected by `$('#container')` if it is a `textarea` or some text input field.

To make use of native functions in recent browsers you should use `input[type="text"]` instead of jQuery's `:text`.